# Drawing this directed graph in Latex

Tags: graphics, diagrams, xfig

I am trying to draw a picture like the following in a Latex document file.

I have tried  to use Xfig, but when I want to draw a line it does not stop. I mean, there is no end point for the line (I use mac).

My question is that is there a program, which is compatible with mac and the pictures can be be exported to a Latex file,  to draw a pictures like the following?

Or is there any way to draw it in xfig?

[image: Any Picture like this]

Comment: See here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/

Comment: @Sigur, thank you for your comment, what I wanted is that to import a kind of free hand draw to a latex document. I need a program to do this drawing.

Comment: If you want to import a raster, take a look at `potrace`.

Comment: But you can draw it in a separate file and then include it.

Comment: @Sigur but this would not be as professional as pictures in, for example, [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.3075&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper.

Comment: @Math757, well I respect your opinion but I don't agree. See for example http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/PDF/graph.pdf You can produce a `pdf`or `eps` figure. But if you want a kind of file to share this figure with other people so that they could edit the image, then I suggest you to use Inkscape wit `svg` file.

Comment: Sorry @Sigur, when I said it wont be so professional, I meant a picture like what I have drawn, thank you again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a solution using `automata` library that one can plot `finite state` showing signals/state changes. Here a style is defined for states.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{state/.style = {
        draw,fill,
        circle,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        minimum size=2pt
    }}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,->,>=stealth', node distance=2cm,semithick]
\node[state] (1) {};
\node[state] (2) [right =2cm of 1] {};
\node[state] (3) [right =2cm of 2] {};
\node[state] (4) [below of =3] {};
\node[state] (5) [left =3cm of 4] {};


\draw[-] (1) -- (2) -- (3)  -- ++(1,0) |- (4) -- (5) -- ++(-2,0) |- (1);
\path    (1) edge [bend left]  node[]{}(4) 
         (4) edge [bend left]  node[]{}(1)
         (3) edge [bend left]  node[]{}(2) 
         (3) edge [loop below] node[]{}(3)
         (5) edge [loop above] node[]{}(5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome @Math757.

Comment: Sorry! Is there any way to make it less curve?(form the first node of the top to the second node of the bottom)

Comment: @Math757 you can use a value for the bending; replace `(4) edge [bend left]  node[]{}(1)` with `(4) edge [bend left=20]  node[]{}(1)` change `20` to the desired value.

Comment: I was thinking  of  `in/out=<angle>` and for example `(1) edge [out=-5,in=140] node[]{}(4)`. But @GonzaloMedina's comment will work too.